# knockout-validation plugin, get isValid from specific property

Tags: knockout-validation

Is is possible to see if just one property is valid in the [knockout-validation plugin](https://github.com/ChampionInternationalMoving/knockout.autocomplete)?

I could not see any reference to it in the documentation, only the ability to see if the whole model is valid.

For example I wish a computed observable to have a different value depending upon if another observable is valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was being led down the wrong direction, as I was using async validators and over complicated my problem, I think it is as simple as:

> propertyName.isValid();

e.g.

> self.email.isValid();

Comment: Hello, @AlexKey. Sorry about this "bump", but I would to know why I am receiving this message from console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isValid' of undefined `. Actually, I know why, but I do not know how to resolve. By chance, it happened to you?

Comment: Hi @chiefGui pop your comment into a question (so the information doesn't get lost in comments) and pop a link to it here and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge FYI, this maybe because you're evaluating the value of the observable and not the observable itself, for example you might be doing `myObservable().isValid()` instead of `myObservable.isValid()`. Just figured that out myself and wanted to share.