# Possible for Knockoutjs custom binding to detect change of css class in element?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I have KO custom binding on an input element and need it to detect if there's been a change (or addition) of a css class for that element. Is this something I detect using a custom binding, or not?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually not a good idea to mix Knockout and other methods to manipulate the DOM.

So in your case it is probably a better idea to set the CSS class using knockout maybe with a computed.
See [knockout js css multiple class bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134066/knockout-js-css-multiple-class-bindings/19134678#19134678)

If the class manipulation is outside your control (for example because it is done by an external plugin). Then you can use something like the [Attr change jquery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) to detect the DOM change and then set an observable with the result (which can then be detected by your custom binding)

Comment: A commendable solution. To be more specific, I'm using KnockoutJS-Validation plug-in which adds an error class to the input field. I need to detect an invalid field and have this passed to the custom binding so I can run jQuery plug-in on that element. Any ideas appreciated pls - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405518/knockoutjs-validation-binding-value-passed-to-custom-binding

Comment: you can use isValid() See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776948/knockout-validation-plugin-get-isvalid-from-specific-property